# Does vSphere ESXI Virtualization needs to be installed on root server or is it an application which can be installed inside an OS?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, dell-poweredge, windows-server-2022

Recently I've bought Dell PowerEdge R620 Server. I am interested in running Windows Server 2022 as well as I am interested in running virtual machines using Virtualization. Now I know that Windows Server 2022 does support Hyper-V using which I can create virtual machine inside Windows Server 2022 (I trust we will need Windows Server 2022 Data Center Edition).

However, I was wondering and little kin to understand How VMWare's vSphere ESXI is different here and if its an application that can/needs to be installed on bare metal root server or can be installed inside an existing OS like windows server 2022.

When the main idea is operating the server with virtualization I was wondering 2 use cases as below -

Use Case 1 -  Installing VMWare vSpehere ESXI on the root bare metal server therefore making the server virtualized and within this I can create multiple virtual machines with supporting OS.

Use Case 2 - Installing Windows Server 2022 and enable Hyper V for supporting Virtualized environment. Windows Server 2022 will give me an upper hand to use the server with direct Windows Server OS on the machine PLUS i can also build virtual machines inside it.

So Essentially in in the Use Case 2, I am able to use a physical server with windows OS as well as virtualized environment if required

But for Use Case 1, my server becomes completely virtualized from the root itself and there will be no scope to use direct OS on the physical machine except for virtual machines.

Let me know if my thoughts are correct and what would be the best way to go ahead here?

Regards
A.

Comment: And reading the documentation is not an option? Your question is answered by reading Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare's vSphere ESXi is a Type 1 hypervisor. You install it on the "bare metal root server".